# Wireless Mouse and keyboard combination with frequent driver issue after Windows updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, wireless-keyboard

I have a pretty basic Dell wireless mouse and keyboard combination, but the problem is very often after Windows updates, they seem to have driver issues and way to fix them usually is to take another mouse, plug it in, log in using On-screen keyboard and finally wait for Windows to play nice.

I was wondering is there a solution to this very frequent problem of mine.

Comment: Though I've seen others complain of the issue, your workaround is quite useful!

Comment: It's very unreliable though. Depends on whether Windows will recognize the second mouse at that specific point of time.

Comment: Another argument for telling Windows Update to never update drivers. This is how to do it: https://www.howtogeek.com/302595/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-automatically-updating-hardware-drivers/

Comment: @daidai so you specifically block driver updates for your mouse and keyboard?